# Why is the vergence of a lens $V = \frac{n - 1}{R}$?

Tags: geometric-optics

Why is the vergence $V$ of a lens has the formula: $V = \frac{n - 1}{R}$.

How to get from $V = \frac{1}{f} $ to  $V = \frac{n - 1}{R}$?

Comment: Is this in reference to the Lens-Maker's formula? (See e.g. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenmak.html)

Comment: Look at the lensmaker's formula for a thin lens. It is the power of an interface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)#Lensmaker's_equation